# how to calculate the angle in Nyquist plot

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

Does anyone know how i can read the angle on the Nyquist plot
without knowing the open loop transfer function?
So by only having the plot.

Comment: A Nyquist plot is a plot of a transferfunction using polar coordinates. 
Hence just measure the angle between the plot and the postive x-axis to determine the angle.

Comment: @CoffeeDrivenOrganism sounds good to me, if you attach an example to this definition, i'll up vote it for sure.